# Javascript - changes are made after resizing window browser

Tags: javascript, infinite-scroll

*I have got infinity scroll plugin on my website. After reaching the bottom I get new products which are as intended. The issue is that some content like "add-to-cart" or "product-price" are not displaying as it should be. For example, there is margins and padding set via js.*

I thought that maybe if I bind this js with **body** element this may work, but I cannot find js that make those changes.**(its Magento website)**

**This is only happening in products that were loaded through infinity plugin. After resizing window everything gets fine.**

Why is this happening? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please may you add an [mcve] of the issue? At the moment all we can do is guess.

Comment: Any tips are appreciated

Comment: What tips? We're not magicians, please help us help you. Add some code (a [mcve]).

Comment: The whole of magneto? No. We'd like a reduced test case, something we can help you with. At the moment it's all guess work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

search for something like

- ".addEventListener('resize'"
- ".resize("
- ".on( "resize"

in firebug's script tab, you may find the eventlistener method and see what happens when it gets fixed when you resize the page.

generally you will have to provide some more information.anything else is guessing